# Check wine branch used

Tags: bash, wine, 22.04

I want to know if I am using wine-stable, wine-devel or wine-staging using bash, how do I do?

Comment: The quickest and most simple way I know is  application_name --version Try for each of the 3 apps.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed Wine from the official repositories, you can see which package has been installed using:

```
apt list --installed winehq-*
```

This will tell you if either the `winehq-stable`, `winehq-devel`, or `winehq-staging` package is installed.

If you installed in another way, you would have to make up your own system to find out what has actually been installed.